# Regular Expression Total Matches on Instances

Tags: javascript, regex

My test string contains 4 instances of an open square bracket and a closed square bracket, so I would like the following regular expression to return 4 matches, but it only returns 1.

```
const test = "sf[[[[asdf]]]]asdf"
const regExp = new RegExp(/^.*\[.*\].*$/, "g");
const matches = test.match(regExp).length;

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: What are you expecting as output? `[[[[asdf]]]], [[[asdf]]], [[asdf]], [asdf]`?

Comment: Yes, but the test string could also look something like this: `st[[as[[asdf]]]a]sdf` and I would still want to receive 4 matches.  However, I see now that if I'm able to write a regular expression for what I want that it should actually return 16 matches instead of 4, which is fine.

Comment: the `.*` in your regEx is used eagerly and is matching the rest of the `[` characters. Use `.*?` for lazy matching.

Comment: `^.*?\[.*?\].*?$` still returns only one match @inquizitive

Comment: Yeah, it looks like any way you do it, it only returns one match. I think you'll need to do it iteratively/recursively, as suggested by @KevBot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a combination of recursion and regular expressions:

```js
function parse(str) {
  const matches = [];

  str.replace(/\[(.*)]/, (match, capture) => {
    matches.push(match, ...parse(capture));
  });

  return matches;
}

console.log(parse('sf[[[[asdf]]]]asdf'));
console.log(parse('st[[as[[asdf]]]a]sdf'));
```